# I can't use MAX() correctly in SQL

Tags: sql, count, group-by, max

Let's say my table is like this:

```
id  code    newCode
-------------------
1   30002   3000231
2   30002   3000232
3   30002   300021
4   30002   300021
5   30009   300093
6   30009   300093
7   30012   3001231
8   30012   3001232
9   30012   300124
10  30012   300121
11  30012   300121
12  30013   3001331
13  30013   3001332
14  30013   300134
```

and I want get the highest number of duplicate in `newCode` (in this case 2  -  for example num 10 and 11 are the same so 2)

My SQL command is:

```
SELECT MAX(c.newCode)
FROM
            SELECT COUNT(c.newCode)
            FROM courseTaun c
            GROUP BY c.newCode
```

and I just get syntax error.

If I run only:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.newCode)
            FROM courseTaun c
            GROUP BY c.newCode
```

I get:

```
COUNT(c.newCode)
2
1
1
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

If I run only

```
SELECT MAX(c.newCode)
FROM courseTaun c
```

I get the value : 300134

Why can't I seem to combine the 2 into giving my the value I need?

Thank you very much for the helpers :)

Comment: What would be the value you need? Just a plain `2`?

Answer (score 1):

*I guess* `NewCode` column was saved as `string`. In order to get the maximum value, you need to cast it to number first,

```
SELECT  MAX(CAST(newCode as SIGNED))
FROM
(
    SELECT  newCode
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY newCode
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*MySQL Version*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b98/3)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  MAX(CAST(newCode as INT))
FROM
(
    SELECT  newCode
    FROM    table1
    GROUP   BY newCode
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*TSQL Version*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2ac6/2)

Comment: +1 -- you're right about converting because the OP gets a value of `300134` instead of `3001332` when executing `SELECT MAX(c.newCode)
FROM courseTaun c`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing **brackets** behind `FROM`

```
... FROM ( statement ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(dups) from (select count(newCode) as dups from courseTaun group by newCode) as temp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command get syntax error, but in SQLServer2005+ you can write query without subquery like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(COUNT(c.newCode)) OVER()
FROM courseTaun c
GROUP BY c.newCode
```